# Cyclical replacement the content of EditText with the limited length

Tags: android, android-edittext

For example, I have EditText with length limitation of two characters. When the first and second letters entered it's ok. But when we will try to enter a third letter the first letter should be replaced with it. Next letter should replace the second and so on in a circle. How can I do this one.

Comment: Which variant shows the expected behavior correctly? 
1. Enter a -> a, Enter b -> ab, Enter c -> bc, Enter d -> cd, Enter e -> de
2. Enter a -> a, Enter b -> ab, Enter c -> cb, Enter d -> cd, Enter e -> ed

Comment: Expected behaviour:  a->a,   b->ab,   c->cb,   d->cd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using TextWatcher on your edit text to achieve the goal

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        private int lastModifiedIndex = 1;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 2) {
                char toReplace = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
                if (lastModifiedIndex == 0) {
                    editText.setText("" + s.charAt(lastModifiedIndex) + toReplace);
                    lastModifiedIndex = 1;
                    editText.setSelection(s.length());
                } else {
                    editText.setText("" + toReplace + s.charAt(lastModifiedIndex));
                    lastModifiedIndex = 0;
                    editText.setSelection(s.length());
                }
            } else {
                lastModifiedIndex = 1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code snippet isn't working as well. Furthermore, due to limitation of EditText length with only two symbols, the "if" statement would not be reachable.

Comment: I see. Then you should remove that limitation from the XML and left only the text watcher - the if statement will do the limitation as well

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException: editText.setSelection(s.length()) ->editText.setSelection(s.length()-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private int charLimit = 5;
        private int position = 5;
        private String newSequence;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (s.length() > charLimit ) {

                if (position == charLimit) {
                    newSequence = s.subSequence(s.length()-1, s.length()).toString() +
                            s.subSequence(1, charLimit);
                        position = 1;

                } else {
                    position++;
                    newSequence = s.subSequence(0, position).toString() +
                            s.subSequence(position+1, s.length());
                }

                editText.setText(null);
                editText.setText(newSequence);
                editText.setSelection(position);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

       }
    });
```